# Manage several git repositories from magit

Tags: magit

I'm maintaining several git repositories using magit, and their
numbers keep growing. Is there a way to inform magit of
all these projects so that a single command would present a summary of
the status of each one instead of manually running `magit-status` on
each one of them ?

Comment: [Thomas Frössman](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9137/thomas-fr%C3%B6ssman) mentioned he implemented something like this: [magit-multi-status.el](https://github.com/thomasf/dotfiles-thomasf-emacs/blob/master/emacs.d/lisp/magit-multi-status.el)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there a way to inform magit of the list of all these projects...

Yes, see `magit-repository-directories` and `magit-repository-directories-depth`.

> ...so that a single command would present a summary of the status of each one

At the time this question was asked such a command did not exist, but now it does. Try `M-x magit-list-repositories` and see the [documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Repository-List.html) : (https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Repository-List.html).

---

You can also list all submodules of a super-repository in a similar fashion using `M-x magit-list-submodules`. Or you can show some of that information directly in the status buffer using:

```
(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook
                        'magit-insert-modules
                        'magit-insert-unpulled-from-pushremote)
```

Then all the modules are listed in a separate section. Modules with changes are listed as usual in *Staged changes* and *Unstaged changes*.  <kbd>RET</kbd> on any of these modules shows the status buffer for that repository and <kbd>q</kbd> takes you back to the status buffer of the super-repository.

Submodules can be fetched using <kbd>f m</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, the submodules seem the way to go. Should I clone my various git repos in this new super-project (and go through some tedious configuration for each one) or can I just move the directories in a common one and then declare each as a submodule?

Comment: You could `mv` the repositories, but  then you would still have to `git submodule add git://<module> <module>` each one of them, but that at least is better than having to setup all the remotes and branches again.

Comment: It seems to be <kbd>f m<kbd> instead of <kbd>F m<kbd> to fech submodules.

Answer (score 3):

Having felt a similar need for managing multiple git repositories simultaneously, I've tried to come up with a solution: https://github.com/luismbo/multi-magit.

Answer (score 0):

Im using simple emacs lisp script which works surprisingly well for me:

```
(setq projects '(
     "git_folder_1" 
     "git_folder_2"
     "... any other number of remaining repos"))

(defun show-dashboard ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (cl-loop for project in projects
    do (magit project)))
```

Then I'm creating a key binding like so:

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-p") 'show-dashboard)
```

And that's it. It should show grid of all your git repos. You can then feely manipulate those windows and hit key binding again to go back to the dashboard.