# Is there a way to view summaries of multiple repositories

Tags: magit, git

I'm using a small script like

```sh
for d in $HOME/Repository/* ; do
   if [[ -n "$(git -C $d status -s)" ]] ; then 
        emacsclient --eval "(magit-status $d)" 
   fi
done
```

to open repositories that need intervention. But I would like to see this info in a buffer in Emacs, preferably a summary of multiple repositories to show which files need merge/commit along with incoming/outgoing info.

Is there a package/configuration for this?

Comment: I read http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19176/manage-several-git-repositories-from-magit?rq=1 before asking but didn't like submodule solution. But rereading, the comment to the question provides a pointer to https://github.com/thomasf/dotfiles-thomasf-emacs/blob/master/emacs.d/lisp/magit-multi-status.el which looks what I need. I'll keep this question for now for other possible solutions

Comment: Could you please summarize the approach you are now using in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm keep all my development repos under a directory and run a script that checks whether a repository needs attention. If so it runs magit via emacsclient. This script is bound to a key sequence in xmonad, so it's not very different than pressing keys in Emacs. But a summary generated by polling all repositories might be better suited to my comfort zone (i.e. Emacs) @tarsius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have implement a command that lists known local repositories in a separate buffer on a feature branch, see [this](https://github.com/magit/magit/pull/2660) pull request.

It will probably be a while until I finish the documentation and merge this branch into `master`, but I think it is quite usable already.

Comment: I did not run this yet, will do so tomorrow but from what I read, this looks fantastic. Will keep testing this and report if any bugs appear. Thank you.